# Can integrals of this type be computed?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I know that integrals like this can be computed using complex analysis:

$$\oint_C \frac{e^z dz}{z^{2}- 2z - 3}  $$

but can the following be integrated using complex analysis?

$$\oint_C \frac{e^z dz}{z^{\alpha}- 2z - 3}  $$

**EDITED**: To be clear, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The important point in this integral is zeros of integrand in $C$, then $\alpha$ must be determined.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ an element of $\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Suppose $\alpha$ is a non-integer, then it can take an infinite number of values which would mean there would be an infinite number of roots? Right?

Comment: That introduces a branch point at the origin, but if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$, for instance, say $\alpha=\frac{p}{q}$, the change of variable $z=w^q$ removes such branch point. So I think you have to be a more more specific about the $\alpha$s you are interested in.

Comment: What is he contour of integration??
Using Either Cauchy Integral Formula (CIF) or Cauchy Integral theorem (CIT), you can definitely evaluate the integral. What is $\alpha$, is it rational? Can you solve for the poles of the integrand. i.e. do you know the solution to $z^{\alpha} - 2z - 3 = 0$?

Comment: The shape of $C$ also matters, since the value on the integral just depends on the singularities enclosed by $C$. The general problem can be tackled by exploiting Cauchy's integral formula on a key-hole contour.

Comment: In what I am looking at is that $\alpha \in$ Reals

Comment: In this case, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$